# Confusion about longitudinal waves

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, waves

I was trying to understand longitudinal waves, when I found the picture below:
[image]

Now Im fine with this until at time T where ball number 1 and 2 get close to each other, so that they should repel each other (because the spring between them is  compressed) but ball number one continues its movement, I understand that if it doesnt there will be no wave, but there is a force acting on ball number 1 right now that would change its amplitude because its expected to have a 0 acceleration in that point, so here is my question why does ball number 1 continues its movement same as before despite the force from ball number 2 acting upon it in the 5th row of this picture?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the row 4,
The ball 1 is being pushed to the right by the spring at the left side of the ball 1 and it is being pulled to the right by the spring at the right side of the ball one.
These two forces continues until the ball 1 reaches the initial point as we see in row 5
That means the ball 1 now has the maximum velocity.
Now the right spring(ball 2) is pushing ball 1 to the left. So the velocity starts to decrease and becomes zero when
Ball 1 is at the maximum position.
And at that point the force is also maximum due to the fact that the both of the springs are compressed and strechted the most. I hope you've got your answer

Comment: Isnt the spring on the left of the ball one in equilibrium when ball one is on the mean position so therefore the spring between particle two and one which is compressed should accelerate the ball to the right?

Comment: It should if the velocity of the ball 1 was already zero. But notice that the velocity has a non zero value at that position. So you can say that the velocity will start to decrease and eventually become zero and then it will start to move in the opposite direction

Comment: Yes I agree with this, the particle at the mean point has its maximum velocity and zero acceleration so at the mean point forces acting on this particle should be in equilibrium but they currently are not in equilibrium, so the amplitude should change, is this assumption true ?

Comment: Yes you're right. But the problem is that the longitude wave doesn't really moves that way. I mean at the mean position the forces will always be equal. But the picture above doesn't show that mainly for simplicity. It's better if you watch a simulation. You'll have a great visualization from this https://ophysics.com/w5.html

Comment: You'll see in this simulation that whenever in the mean position, strechted length of both of the springs are equal